# How to change UIMenu alignment and font in Swift?

Tags: swift, uimenu

I want to change UIMenu alignment and font.
There is a identifier in UIMenu

```
open class UIMenu : UIMenuElement {
    /// Unique identifier.
    open var identifier: UIMenu.Identifier { get }
}
```

And there is a extension for it

```
extension UIMenu.Identifier {
    /// Align Left, Center, Justify, Align Right menu
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    public static let alignment: UIMenu.Identifier
}

let menu = UIMenu(title: "", image: nil, identifier: nil, options: [], children: menuItems)
```

I want to set right value for it but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: The `UIMenu.Identifier.alignment` is an identifier of a standard menu item (if you want to add such in your menu), but not an `alignment` property of menu item itself. `UIMenuElement` does not support features as you want for now.